# NGINX redirecting non secure subdomain to main domain

Tags: nginx

I have 2 domain hosted on the same server let's say `testwebsite.com` and `staging.testwebsite.com`. I have added the nginx configuration in which there is one problem subdomain is getting redirected to main domain only on non secure protocol.

http://testwebsite.com -> https://testwebsite.com = OK

https://testwebsite.com -> https://testwebsite.com = OK

**http://staging.testwebsite.com -> https://testwebsite.com = NOT OK**

https://staging.testwebsite.com -> https://staging.testwebsite.com = OK

**testwebsite.com**

```
server {
    root /var/www/testwebsite.com/live;
    index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name testwebsite.com www.testwebsite.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/testwebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/testwebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name testwebsite.com www.testwebsite.com;
    return 301 https://testwebsite.com$request_uri;

}
```

**staging.testwebiste.com**

```
server {
    root /var/www/testwebsite.com/staging;
    index index.html index.php index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name staging.testwebsite.com www.staging.testwebsite.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.testwebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/staging.testwebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot




}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name staging.testwebsite.com www.staging.testwebsite.com;
    return 301 https://staging.testwebsite.com$request_uri;

}
```

Can anyone please help what went wrong with the config?

Comment: It seems that on your staging box, the `return 301 https://staging.testwebsite.com$request_uri;` is forcing the redirect, as it listens on port 80 and sends the 301 to https

Comment: @JavierLarroulet it should go to `https://staging.testwebsite.com` instead of going to `https://testwebsite.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config looks OK to me.

Are you sure that it is not your browser caching the redirect? Browsers tend to cache 301 redirects very aggressively.

Comment: Thanks man it worked! Wasted so many hours in already working config.